# Theorem 3.42 Principles of Mathematical Analysis (baby Rudin), How am I wrong?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification

In PMA (baby Rudin), Rudin states that:

> Suppose $$$$ (a) the partial sums $A_n$ of $\Sigma a_n$ form a bounded sequence; $$$$ (b) $b_0 \geq b_1 \geq b_2 \geq \dots$ ;$$$$ (c) $\lim_{n\to\infty}{bn} = 0$. $$$$ Then $\Sigma a_n b_n$ converges.

In proof, he says that:

> Choose M such that $\lvert A_n \rvert \leq M$ for all $n$. Given $\epsilon > 0$ ... $$\lvert \sum_{n=p}^{q} a_n b_n \rvert = \lvert\sum_{n=p}^{q-1} A_n (b_n - b_{n+1}) + A_q b_q - A_{p-1} b_p\rvert \leq M \lvert\sum_{n=p}^{q-1} (b_n - b_{n+1}) + b_q + b_p\rvert.$$

I had problems with the last inequality so I tried to Calculate it myself; My calculations are as follows (note that $\lvert M \rvert = M$)
$$\lvert\sum_{n=p}^{q-1} A_n (b_n - b_{n+1}) + A_q b_q - A_{p-1} b_p\rvert = M.\frac{1}{\lvert M \rvert}\lvert\sum_{n=p}^{q-1} A_n (b_n - b_{n+1}) + A_q b_q - A_{p-1} b_p\rvert = M \lvert\sum_{n=p}^{q-1} \frac{A_n}{M} (b_n - b_{n+1}) + \frac{A_q}{M} b_q - \frac{A_{p-1}}{M} b_p\rvert \leq M \lvert\sum_{n=p}^{q-1} (b_n - b_{n+1}) + b_q - b_p\rvert = 0 \leq \epsilon$$

but I know my calculations have to be wrong since I didn't use (b) or (c); Is anyone kind enough to point out my mistakes?

Comment: $|a+b-c|\le |a'+b'-c'|$ need not hold when $|a|\le a', |b|\le b'$ and $|c| \le c'$. Ex: $a=0, b=-1, c=1, a'=0, b'=1, c'=1$

Comment: You are implicitly using that $b_p,b_q, b_n-b_{n+1}\geq 0$, which is implied by (b) and (c)

Comment: @JulioPuerta Even if those conditions hold, OP's manipulations are wrong.

Comment: Yes, but the correct proof uses that fact (along with triangle inequality)